# Bind Visibility to ReactiveCommand CanExecute

Tags: wpf, visibility, system.reactive, reactiveui, canexecute

I have several Tiles ([TileLayoutControl Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/clsDevExpressXpfLayoutControlTileLayoutControltopic)) in my xaml (**only shown 2 in this example**) whose Visibility are binded to Boolean Properties and converted through BooleanToVisibilityConverter.
This works just fine.  My question is

**Can I bind the visibility to the Command instead so that I can remove the need of those several Boolean Properties?**

Something like binding the Visibility to **Command.CanExecute**

If Yes, How can I achieve that? Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks.

```
<dxlc:Tile Command="{Binding Tile1Command}"
           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTile1Visible , Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<dxlc:Tile Command="{Binding Tile2Command}"
           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTile2Visible , Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
private bool _isTile1Visible;
public bool IsTile1Visible
{
    get { return _isTile1Visible; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isTile1Visible, value); }
}

public ReactiveCommand Tile1Command { get; private set; }

Tile1Command = new ReactiveCommand();
Tile1Command.Subscribe(p => PerformTile1Operation());
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just use RxUI bindings:

```
<dxlc:Tile x:Name="Tile1" />
```

Then in your View constructor (make sure to implement `IViewFor<Tile1ViewModel>` to get this extension):

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Tile1Command);

this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.Tile1Command.CanExecuteObservable)
    .BindTo(this, x => x.Tile1.Visibility);
```

You could also solve this in the ViewModel level, though that's not what I would do - in the ViewModel ctor:

```
Tile1Command = new ReactiveCommand(/* ... */);
Tile1Command
    .Select(x => x ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Tile1Visibility, out tile1Visibility);
```

Comment: I think the "not what I would do" relates to whether you like writing code (for binding) in the view - conceptually I prefer binding in markup but then again maybe I need to learn more new tricks

Comment: I've worked out what bothers me, one of the nice things about bindings in the markup is that you don't have to give the XAML elements names. Colour me strange but I think that's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

ReactiveCommand is an `ICommand` implementation that is simultaneously a `RelayCommand` implementation...

Assume that the ReactiveCommand has been declared like this...

```
public ReactiveCommand FileCommand { get; private set; }
```

...and has been instantiated in a View Model like this...

```
SomeText = "";
FileCommand = new ReactiveCommand(this.WhenAny(vm => vm.SomeText, s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Value)));
FileCommand.Subscribe(param => MessageBox.Show("Processing"));
```

... which means if the property SomeText is empty, then the command cannot be executed, otherwise the command can be executed.  And if the command is executed, a message box will get displayed.

If your objective is to simply eliminate the boolean `IsTile1Visible`, you can make a Xaml declaration like this...

```
<Button Content="File" 
        Command="{Binding FileCommand}"
        Visibility="{Binding FileCommand, Converter={genericMvvm1:CommandToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

where the visibility is bound to the same command and uses a value converter...

and the value converter looks like this...

```
public class CommandToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            ICommand iCommand = value as ICommand;
            if (iCommand != null)
            {
                if (iCommand.CanExecute(parameter))
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The value converter simply dereferences the command into a basic ICommand and converts it into a visibility.  Note that since this converter inherits from `Markup Extension`, there's no need to declare it as a static resource in the Xaml's object graph.

NOTE: the same functionality can be achieved by using 'code-behind' available in ReactiveUI, but the Xaml/ValueConverter appeals to developers who do not want their View Models to deal explicitly with the 'Visibility' property.

Comment: It certainly works (i.e. doesn't fail), but it's not the Right Way To Do Things™ - SO is a source of *Documentation*, I want people to know how to do things correctly with ReactiveUI.

Comment: @PaulBetts, can you clarify what you mean by the "Right Way to do Things"?

Comment: I like convertors - they are part of the broader XAML patterns - that said @PaulBetts shows a way to surface a visibility property in the ViewModel as well as to do so through code based binding. Interesting.

Comment: @Murph, in this case the converter is more extensible than code-behind, and Rx is certainly more robust and flexible than Paul would have you believe.  There are MANY ways to do things!  :)

Comment: In this code, how does the converter get called again when the CanExecute expression is re-evaluated? I'm asking this because it's not working with a `RoutedUICommand`.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do that, but it would require subclassing the command so that it also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the underlying condition would need to raise `PropertyChange` for the `CanExecute` property whenever it changes.

It won't work without that, as `ICommand` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - it uses `CanExecuteChanged` instead.

Note that you could simplify the property, however, by just handling it yourself in the constructor:

```
// In constructor:
Tile1Command = new ReactiveCommand();
Tile1Command.Subscribe(p => PerformTile1Operation());

IReactiveObject self = this as IReactiveObject;

Tile1Command.CanExecuteChanged += (o,e) => self.RaisePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTile1Visible"));
```

Then your property becomes:

```
// Use command directly here...
public bool IsTile1Visible
{
    get { return Tile1Command.CanExecute; }
}
```

Comment: There are much easier ways to do this, see my answer

Comment: @PaulBetts Good to know - looks like you've built a lot of interesting functionality around these types of requirements.